# Which sentence would be the correct?or both?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

> Is it necessary that word for the sentence to make sense?
>
> Is that word necessary for the sentence to make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct:
"Is that word necessary for the sentence to make sense?"

For the first example to be correct, it would require heavy alteration:

"Is it necessary for that word to be inserted into the sentence in order for it to make sense?"